# correct syntax for if statement to check dbnull inline asp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am looking for some help on the syntax to check for DBNull inline in asp...

```
<EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# If(isDBNull(Eval("activeType")).Value, False, Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("activeType"))) %>'></asp:CheckBox>
 </EditItemTemplate>
```

Hoping someone can show me the light on this one..

Thanks,

Comment: you can use ternay operator to accomplish the same.

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: The `.Value` seems incorrect, remove it and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you had it fine , just take out `.Value`   , `isDBNull(Eval("activeType"))`  this will work , you can not get the Value of dbNull , so the exception is thrown before it actually gets to check if it's null

```
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# If(isDBNull(Eval("activeType")), False, Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("activeType"))) %>'></asp:CheckBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: UPDATE is not posting the value back to the database. Correctly removes True, but also does not place False back in database.